# OpenLayers Drag&Drop a pin to select position?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

Is there an OpenLayers example that allows the user to set a position with drag&drop.
I would like to have a pin and set the position after the user drags & drops the pin to a new position.

Comment: like http://www.macfh.co.uk/JavaJive/ProgScriptWeb/UKOSOpenLayers.html ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this one now: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/drag-feature.html
Still need to find a way to use marker instead of point though